# where to change git user

Tags: git, delphi

i use embarcadero Delphi version 10.3.3

- i setup user in "tools-options-version control-git"
- next i open "file-open from version control..." - "git" - fill ssh link and local path like a
  ssh://ubuntuUser@mydomain:/home/git/project.git
  C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\project
- press ok
- have error

```
"...
Permission denied, please try again.
compname+User@mydomain: Permission denied (publickey, password).
..."
```

so user from my link changed to system username and i have no more ideas where change it. this error is only on one computer. help me please.

also this error only if I create a new project from the repository. version control is ok if at the beginning I copy the project using cmd.

Comment: As far ass I know Delphi doesn't support full GIT integration. Instead it uses API calls to talk with GIT client itself and then the GIT client takes care about updating GIT repository or retrieving files from GIT repository. In order to change login information for specific GIT project you will most likely have to use GIT client itself. Delphi is just reading the GIT information that is stored in your projects folder. That is why copying project from another computer works since this way you also copy GIT settings for that project.

Comment: True, @SilverWarior, but it's common for Git integrations to work like that. I think also Visual Studio, and even git clients like SourceTree, GitKraken and many others will just wrap the Git CLI and read its output, although it will depend on the client which calls are supported in the UI and which are not. I'm not sure, but I can imagine that Delphi indeed supports the file interactions, pull, commit, but not the configuring of Git itself.

Comment: @SilverWarior sorry, i mean "clone" project. and I still don't know where delphi gets the "compname + User" user from for git

Comment: If you clear your authentication information fro Delphi Options it should open a login dialog when you try to Clone, Pull or Commit your project to GIT repository that is password protected. If after this the problem still persists with same error then the cause might be on a SSH level instead of a GIT.